# Binary Tree insert element - only works for inserting the root, not any other nodes

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I am learning about algorithms. I understand how to implement a binary tree, but my `insert` code doesn't work: when I start with an empty tree and call `insert` to insert a few values to the tree, it only inserts the root node, but not any other nodes.

Could you explain me why?

```java
public class Tree {

    private class Node {
        int value;
        Node leftChild;
        Node rightChild;

        public Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Node=" + value;
        }
    }

    private Node root;

    public void insert(int value) {
        var node = new Node(value);
        if(root == null) {
            root = node;
            return;
        }

        var current = root;

        while (current != null) {
            if(value > current.value) {
                current = current.rightChild;
            }
            else {
                current = current.leftChild;
            }
        }

        current = node;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current = node` does not mutate the tree. It looks like you expect that when `current` becomes `null` -- after having travelled to the left or right of a leaf node -- that this assignment would update that leaf's left/right field. That is not true. This assignment only affects the `current` variable, and nothing else.

You need to keep track of which was the leaf you traversed to, and then update that leaf's left/right field.

Here is the corrected code:

```java
public void insert(int value) {
    var node = new Node(value);
    if (root == null) {
        root = node;
        return;
    }

    var current = root;

    while (true) {
        if (value > current.value) {
            if (current.rightChild == null) {
                // Don't make current null, but update its field
                current.rightChild = node;
                break;
            }
            current = current.rightChild;
        }
        else {
            if (current.leftChild == null) {
                // Don't make current null, but update its field
                current.leftChild = node;
                break;
            }
            current = current.leftChild;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Added only 3 parts:

- added parent node index => `Node parent = null;`
- updated the parent node with current => `parent = current;`
- updated the parent's reference to the new node (shown in below)

Code:

```
public void insert(int value) {
    var node = new Node(value);
    if (root == null) {
        root = node;
        return;
    }

    var current = root;
    Node parent = null;   // <= define parent index as null

    while (current != null) {
        parent = current; // <= update the parent before moving to the next level

        if (value > current.value) {
            current = current.rightChild;
        } else {
            current = current.leftChild;
        }
    }

    if (value > parent.value) {  // <= update the parent's reference to the new node
        parent.rightChild = node;
    } else {
        parent.leftChild = node;
    }
}
```

You can also view and test the code here:  http://tpcg.io/_9BCIWR

Test Code:

```
public class Tree {

    private class Node {
        int value;
        Node leftChild;
        Node rightChild;

        public Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Node=" + value;
        }
    }

    private Node root;

    public void insert(int value) {
        var node = new Node(value);
        if (root == null) {
            root = node;
            return;
        }

        var current = root;
        Node parent = null; // <= define parent index as null

        while (current != null) {
            parent = current; // <= update the parent before moving to the next level

            if (value > current.value) {
                current = current.rightChild;
            } else {
                current = current.leftChild;
            }
        }

        if (value > parent.value) {   // <= update the parent's reference to the new node
            parent.rightChild = node;
        } else {
            parent.leftChild = node;
        }
    }

    public void printInOrder() {
        System.out.println("In-order traversal:");
        printInOrder(root);
    }

    private void printInOrder(Node root) {
        if (root != null) {
            printInOrder(root.leftChild);
            System.out.println(root);
            printInOrder(root.rightChild);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tree tree = new Tree();

        tree.insert(10);
        tree.insert(5);
        tree.insert(15);
        tree.insert(3);
        tree.insert(7);
        tree.insert(12);
        tree.insert(18);

        tree.printInOrder();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
In-order traversal:
Node=3
Node=5
Node=7
Node=10
Node=12
Node=15
Node=18
```